# Create Twilio Conference With Rest API

Tags: rest, twilio, conference

I'm looking to create a Twilio Conference through the rest API. And I'm not sure how to start the conference. I'd prefer to do this without the SDK.

Heres the flow that I'm looking for.

- In browser I enter a phone number to be called and click a call button.
- A request is sent to my server. I handle my back end logic.
- In PHP the rest API is used to hit Twilio and start a conference. (Hopefully connect the initial user via JS Client in this request)
- Once the connection is established use the callback request to add a phone number to the conference.

I have used rest for outbound calls but I can't figure out how to set up a conference.

For outbound calls I use the rest endpoint https://api.twilio.com/version/Accounts/account/Calls.JSON
What would the endpoint be for creating a conference and adding the client?

I found https://api.twilio.com/version/Accounts/account/confrences.JSON
but it seems to be geared toward get requests for pulling data about conferences not creating an outbound conference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you're saying that you'd like to make Twilio calls from the browser without the [Twilio Client JS SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js), then I can't help you there. We don't publish the API and it's not recommended you try to write your own library.

You can achieve the flow you want here. You can [use the REST API to generate a call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls) to [your client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls?code-sample=code-make-an-outbound-call-to-a-twilio-client&code-language=php&code-sdk-version=5.x):

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "your_account_sid";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $client->calls->create(
    "client:CLIENT_IDENTITY", "YOUR TWILIO NUMBER",
    array("url" => "YOUR APPLICATION URL")
);
```

Note, you need to use `client:CLIENT_IDENTITY` as the to number.

The URL you pass to this call should point to an endpoint on your server that will return the TwiML to start the conference:

```
<Response>
  <Dial><Conference>Conference room name</Conference></Dial>
<Response>
```

During this request that you return the conference TwiML, you can also kick off a new request to start a call to the phone number you want to dial, again using the REST API.

Does this all make sense?

Comment: The REST API is what I was looking for.

Got everything working thanks.

Comment: @philnash conference call rest api. Where can I found it...?

Comment: @NomanJaved Right here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference

Comment: @philnash how can i convert this syntax to rest api syntax `<Dial ringTone="bg" action="<?php echo $str ?>" timeout="25"><Client><?php echo $tw_agent_id; ?></Client>
                    </Dial>`

Comment: @NomanJaved Check the documentation and example here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls?code-sample=code-make-an-outbound-call-to-a-twilio-client&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=5.x